# Pass an array into custom component in NextJs

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I'm having some trouble passing data into a custom component in my NextJS app in TypeScript. I have a custom component (not in pages folder) defined as:

```
import { Trip } from '../components/models'

export const TripsComponent = (data: Trip[]) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Your Trips</h1>
            <div>
                {data.map((trip: Trip) => (
                    <div className="card">
                        <h3>{trip.name}</h3>
                    </div>
                ))}
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default TripsComponent
```

Trip is a custom type defined as:

```
type Trip = {
    id: string;
    user_id: string;
    name: string;
}
```

And I have a page in /pages defined as:

```
import axios from 'axios'
import { GetStaticProps, InferGetStaticPropsType, NextPage } from 'next'
import { Trip } from '../components/models'
import TripsComponent from '../components/trips-component'

const TripsPage: NextPage = (data: InferGetStaticPropsType<typeof getStaticProps>) => {
    console.log(data)
    return (
        <div className="container">
            <TripsComponent data={data} />
        </div>
    )
}

type GetTripsResponse = {
    data: Trip[]
}

const apiURL = 'http://localhost:3001/trips/'

export const getStaticProps: GetStaticProps = async (context) => {
    try {
        const { data, status } = await axios.get<GetTripsResponse>(apiURL, {
            headers: {
                Accept: 'application/json',
            },
        })
        //console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 4))
        return {
            props: {
                data,
            },
        }
    } catch (e) {
        return {
            notFound: true,
        }
    }
}

export default TripsPage
```

The `console.log(data)` has data and it's shape is:

```
{
  data: [
    {
      id: '0b68a50a-8377-4720-94b4-fabdabc12da1',
      user_id: 'Test1',
      name: 'Test1'
    },
    {
      id: '358ea2eb-d487-4932-b7ad-0ce155f41bbf',
      user_id: 'Test2',
      name: 'Test2'
    },
    {
      id: '4a7a0ecd-fb80-4138-96e6-3bac9551ab02',
      user_id: 'Test2',
      name: 'Test2'
    },
    {
      id: '6726f3ab-6036-4a75-9499-0bf0e8fb1fcf',
      user_id: 'Test3',
      name: 'Test3'
    },
  ]
}
```

How can I pass this data into TripsComponent so it can render the view?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A React component gets its JSX Attributes as the first parameter in form of an Object "called" props:

```
<Hello data={["hi"]}></Hello>
const Hello = ({data})=> (...)
```

Your TripsComponent should be changed accordingly:

```
import { Trip } from '../components/models'

export const TripsComponent = ({data}: {data:Trip[]}) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Your Trips</h1>
            <div>
                {data.map((trip: Trip) => (
                    <div className="card">
                        <h3>{trip.name}</h3>
                    </div>
                ))}
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default TripsComponent
```

In your `getStaticProps` function you need to return an Object `Props` which will become the Props Object of your page. You return prop.data but you named props data in `getStaticProps` this is where the confusion is coming from:

```
// getStaticProps...
       return {
            props: {
                data,
            },
        }
```

```
const TripsPage: NextPage = ({data}: InferGetStaticPropsType<typeof getStaticProps>) => {
    console.log(data)
    return (
        <div className="container">
            <TripsComponent data={data} />
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Thanks for taking a look! I made the change to the TripsComponent as you suggest, but how do I pass it in my page? `<TripsComponent data={data} />` does not seem to work.

Comment: @FlameDra did you console.log your data in `TripsComponent`?

Comment: Ah i see you have the same problem with your nextjs Page. `getStaticProps` returns `{data}` your Page gets it as data -> {data}

Comment: Ah doing `<TripsComponent data={data.data} />` seems to resolve it. Is this the proper way to do it in NextJS or is there some convention which i don't know of?

Comment: Yes that or destructuring data like in my example (TripsPage = ({data}))
That's how you do it. Just name your data, not data, maybe trips. Then you don't confuse it. :)